# Start rasa x service needed EC2 instance using docker container which uses docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I just want to start ec2 instance in dockercontainer which uses aws cli or ubuntu or python docker image but when i tried i got this

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
> [parameters] To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help aws  help  aws  
> help aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices
> are:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:2.7.21
RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id HOJO
RUN aws configure set aws_secret_access_key JOJO
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/local/bin/aws" ]
CMD ["sh","-c","ec2 help"]

# FROM ubuntu:jammy-20220801

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#     software-properties-common
# RUN add-apt-repository universe
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
#     curl \
#     python3.4 \
#     python3-pip
# RUN pip install awscli

# # RUN aws configure set aws_access_key_id HOJO
# # RUN aws configure set aws_secret_access_key JOJO
# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/aws"]

# CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","aws ec2 help"]
```

Help me out with this cause I wanted to add this container in ECS task so this EC2 cant start automatic when ECS restart.I dont want to try lambda fucntion.

Comment: EC2 is a virtual computer where you can run your applications. The ECS solution helps you run an application in a docker container. its not very clear what you are trying to do. can you explain?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @ArunKamalanathan  thank you guys for reaching out to me ,actually we are using rasa bot which runs in ECS fargate and rasa x in EC2 ,so here bot needs rasa x service running which is EC2 instance running and I want to do it by creating a docker container where bot is in ECS which has bot service and in it 3 containers running.But I solved it by hitting api using curl in docker container .